# FullCalendar: Set a Default Date on Add New Event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and am trying to customize some of the functionality.

My question of what i want to do is:

When I add an event to the calendar, is there a way that I can default all New Events to add to the Date "1/1/2010"?

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you are creating the event
I'm doing something like this in dayClick callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            disableResizing: false,
            defaultEventMinutes: 90,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
            var eventObject = {
                    title: "{{user}}"
            };
            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
            eventObject.start = new Date("put default date here");
            date2 = new Date(date)
            date2.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+90) 
            eventObject.end = date2;
            eventObject.id = new Date().getTime();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2012,2,20),"month");

Comment: I'm not aware of fullcalendar supporting default dates for events, so you need to create it with some date. so you can create event as above. or eventObject = {title : "some title", start: new Date("XXX"), end: new Date("YYY")}

Comment: There is a dateClick function that I am trying to figure out how to use.

Comment: I updated the answer with the dayClick function I'm using in my project